# Put more than 1 row into mysql from a php array variable in an html form - not working with []?

Tags: mysql, html, arrays, forms

The line below is part of a form.  When the form is submitted, it enters a row into a mysql table.

$varw has to go in different numbers of rows.  Sometimes there are a lot of $varw's.  I tried changing 'Weight' to 'Weight[]' in the line below only.  That entered 0 (wrong) for $varw in mysql.  And it still only added 1 row.

```
Print "<input type='hidden' name='Weight' value=" . $varw . ">";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need iteration! In other words .. a loop.

Heavily commented untested example below:

```
$i = 0; // Needed to have different variable names
foreach($varw as $var){
   print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"". weight{$i} . "\" value=\"" . $var . "\">";
   $i++; // increment counter on each iteration ... 
}

//  You will now have as many hidden fields as $varw's.
```

I am leaving you the pleasure of thinking up the loop that will do the insertions in database.

Read the manual on [for loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php),

Happy coding friend.

PS: Please, don't start variable names and function names with capital letter.

Comment: This produces this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/blah/public_html/blah.php on line 39

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mysql deleminator ';' to seprate two queries and use it in a loop

Answer (score 0):

You could always use JSON or comma separates values (via `implode()`)

```
Print "<input type='hidden' name='Weight' value=" . json_encode($varw) . ">";
```

On your PHP side when you receive this you could use `json_decode()` back into an array or use `explode()` via "," to split it into array if you decided on using comma separated values.